# Jquery get id from element and include in post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
$(".v1").click(function(){
$.post("inc.php?action=vote&id="$(this).attr('id')"&vote=1");
});

$(".v2").click(function(){
$.post("inc.php?action=vote&id="$(this).attr('id')"&vote=2");
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` == `this.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string to your variable content, using `+` operator, like this:

```
$.post("inc.php?action=vote&id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&vote=1");
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `+` between concatenations

```
$(".v1").click(function(){
$.post("inc.php?action=vote&id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&vote=1");
});

$(".v2").click(function(){
$.post("inc.php?action=vote&id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&vote=2");
});
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-) P.S, why are you sending the data as query string and not as POST body